# I have a problem creating a function, can't resolve the issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem creating a function in T-SQL.

```
USE DB_ASSIG1
BEGIN
    CREATE FUNCTION myFunction (@date DATETIME)
        RETURNS INT
            AS
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @day INT

                CASE SELECT DATENAME(dw, @date)
                    WHEN 'Monday'
                        THEN SET @day = 1
                    WHEN 'Tuesday'
                        THEN SET @day = 2
                    WHEN 'Wednesday'
                        THEN SET @day = 3
                    WHEN 'Thursday'
                        THEN SET @day = 4
                    WHEN 'Friday'
                        THEN SET @day = 5
                    WHEN 'Saturday'
                        THEN SET @day = 6
                    WHEN 'Sunday'
                        THEN SET @day = 7
                    END

                    RETURN (@day)
            END
END
```

Can't resolve it please help, by the way i'm kinda newish to T-SQL.

This is the error i get:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FUNCTION'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
Must declare the scalar variable "@date".

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Must declare the scalar variable "@day".

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 26
Must declare the scalar variable "@day".

Completion time: 2020-05-22T22:54:38.4427014+02:00

Comment: *I have a problem* is too vague. *What problem* are you having specifically?

Comment: Updated: i posted all errors i get.

Comment: Well, you can't create a function within a `begin`/`end` block. Aside: Is there some reason you're trying to write [`DatePart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. You can offset it to start on Monday = 1.

Comment: It is the same with or without begin/end block

Comment: How about [`go`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) after `use`? `Create function` needs to be the first statement in a _batch_.

Comment: Same with go/go, begin/end, same errors nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Create function` must be the first statement in a batch. [`Go`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) terminates a batch, e.g. the one containing the `use` statement.

The function can be made independent of `DateFirst` and `Language` thusly:

```
USE DB_ASSIG1

go -- Required batch separator.

create function dbo.someoneelsesCode( @Date as Date )
  -- Returns the day-of-the-week for the date with Monday = 1 through Sunday = 7.
  -- It is unaffected by the setting of   DateFirst   or   Language .
  returns Int
  begin
  return ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, @Date ) - 2 ) % 7 + 1;
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the problem was with Go, but that was not the only problem, in begin/end block must be return so this works perfectly:

USE DB_ASSIG1

GO


 CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(@date DATETIME)

  RETURNS INT

   BEGIN

    RETURN 
    (
     SELECT CASE DATENAME(DW, @date)
      WHEN 'Monday'
       THEN 1
      WHEN 'Tuesday'
       THEN 2
      WHEN 'Wednesday'
       THEN 3
      WHEN 'Thursday'
       THEN 4
      WHEN 'Friday'
       THEN 5
      WHEN 'Saturday'
       THEN 6
      WHEN 'Sunday'
       THEN 7
     END
    )
   END
GO

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea...

```
 CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.NumericDOW
        (@pDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TINYINT AS
  BEGIN --==== Note that -53690 is the 1st of January, 1753, which is a Monday
        RETURN DATEDIFF(dd,-53690,@pDate)%7+1
    END
;
```

While I certainly understand the idea of abstracting such formula's for ease of use, I personally wouldn't use this in a Scalar Function because it will automatically be about 7 times slower than inline code.  If you can't remember the number -53690, then use "0", which is the 1st of January, 1900, which is also a Monday and a whole lot easier to remember.  The formula would look like this...

```
DATEDIFF(dd,0,@pDate)%7+1
```

As a bit of an educational sidebar, both -53690 and 0 are "Date Serial Numbers" based on the 1st of January, 1900 being "day zero".  "Date Serial Numbers" are a powerful tool for things like this and for generating sequences of dates.